# 2 same foreign keys in one table. Fluent Api generate 3 foreign key instead of 2

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

My problem is in EF Core 2.2 with Fluent API. I need to generate 3 foreign keys in one table instead of 2, it generates `EmployeeId` that is not required for my table.

Here is my code:

```
builder.ToTable("RequestTracking", "Communication");
        builder.Property(r => r.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.HasOne(r => r.Request)
            .WithMany(r => r.RequestTrackings);
        builder.HasOne(r => r.Employee)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(r => r.FromEmployeeId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        builder.HasOne(r => r.Employee)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(r => r.ToEmployeeId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

public class RequestTracking
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public Request Request { get; set; }
    public int FromEmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int ToEmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public AppUser User { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EmployeeStatus> EmployeesStatus { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Resignation> Resignations { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RequestTracking> RequestTrackings { get; set; }
}
```

I also tried this:

```
builder.ToTable("RequestTracking", "Communication");
        builder.Property(r => r.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.HasOne(r => r.Request)
            .WithMany(r => r.RequestTrackings);
        builder.HasOne(r => r.FromEmployee)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(r => r.FromEmployeeId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        builder.HasOne(r => r.ToEmployee)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(r => r.ToEmployeeId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

public class RequestTracking
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public Request Request { get; set; }
    public int FromEmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Employee FromEmployee { get; set; }
    public int ToEmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Employee ToEmployee { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the generated Table by EF Core

```
CREATE TABLE [Communication].[RequestTracking] 
(
    [Id]             INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [RequestId]      INT NOT NULL,
    [FromEmployeeId] INT NOT NULL,
    [ToEmployeeId]   INT NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeId]     INT NULL, // Here is my problem it generates this column

    CONSTRAINT [PK_RequestTracking] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_RequestTracking_Employee_EmployeeId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([EmployeeId]) REFERENCES [HR].[Employee] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_RequestTracking_Request_RequestId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([RequestId]) REFERENCES [Communication].[Request] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_RequestTracking_Employee_ToEmployeeId] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([ToEmployeeId]) REFERENCES [HR].[Employee] ([Id])
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Figure Out what is the problem, I add 2 `ICollection<RequestTracking>` in `Employee`

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public AppUser User { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EmployeeStatus> EmployeesStatus { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Resignation> Resignations { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RequestTracking> RequestTrackingsFrom { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RequestTracking> RequestTrackingsTo { get; set; }
}
```